# function runs all conditionals, ignores current variables

Tags: javascript

I created some divs; their innerHTML properties get changed according to the current image shown (defined by `imageArray[value]`). The problem I have is that conditionals in this function do not work as they should. This function runs every statement and stops at the values in the last conditional bracket. It could be a logic issue or a missing piece of code, but I would like to have your thoughts on how this problem can be solved.

This function gets triggered through `prevImage()` or `nextImage()`:

```
function textChange(){

var titleMod = document.getElementById('title');
var dateMod = document.getElementById('date');
var infoMod = document.getElementById('info');
var pagelink = document.getElementById('enter');

if(new_image = imageArray[0]){

    titleMod.innerHTML = "This is Image 1";
    dateMod.innerHTML = "july 12 12";
    infoMod.innerHTML = "<p>paragraph goes in here</p>";
    pagelink.onclick = "window.location.href='house.html';"

    alert('\o/');

    }

if(new_image = imageArray[1]){

    titleMod.innerHTML = "This is Image 2";
    dateMod.innerHTML = "july 12 19";
    infoMod.innerHTML = "<p>paragraph</p>";
    pagelink.onclick = "window.location.href='contact.html';"

    alert('lolol');

    }

if(new_image = imageArray[2]){

    titleMod.innerHTML = "This is Image 3";
    dateMod.innerHTML = "july 12 19";
    infoMod.innerHTML = "<p>paragraph</p>";
    pagelink.onclick = "window.location.href='contact.html';"

    alert('thisWorks');

    }

}
```

Comment: `if (x = y)` will always be true. `==`!

Comment: It would have been fine to show a single example, and reduce it to just a few lines.

Comment: @elclanrs only if `y` is truthy. `!!(x = 0) === false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your conditionals use assignment instead of comparison.

`new_image = imageArray[2]` sets `new_image` to the value of `imageArray[2]`, which is a truthy value. You need to compare the two things instead, eg.

```
new_image === imageArray[2]
```

As for why they're all running, instead of it short-circuiting as soon as the first condition is met, it's because you're using a sequence of independent `if` statements as opposed to a chain of `if`, `else if` and `else`.

```
if(new_image === imageArray[0]){
  ...
} else if(new_image === imageArray[1]){
  ...
} else if(new_image === imageArray[2]){
  ...
} else {
  // new_image doesn't meet any of the previous conditions
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your tips, i'll keep them in mind when dealing with conditionals and variables in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the affectation operator "=" in your test instead of "==".

> (new_image = imageArray[1])

Always returns true

> (new_image == imageArray[1])

Tests for equality ("===" would test for strict equality)

Answer (score 0):

Your conditionals will always return true. This is because you are setting `new_image` to the value of `imageArray[#]`.

```
if(new_image = imageArray[0]){
```

Note that in the above line you are using a single equal sign instead of the double equal sign that tests for equality. The single equal sign is an assignment operator.

Instead, the line should be written as:

```
if(new_image == imageArray[0]){
```

You could also use `===` which does a strict comparison of the two values. This is useful if you would like to compare the `types` of the two values as well.

So why does an assignment always equal true? Well technically it doesn't always. The value that is on the right of the equal sign is the one being tested by JavaScript. JavaScript will convert this value to a boolean and it just so happens that quite a lot of values when converted to booleans become the boolean `TRUE`. In your particular case, you are testing Strings. Any `String` when converted to a `Boolean` with a length greater than 0 will evaluate to `TRUE`, hence why your code is not functioning as you want it to function.

Comment: Why not `===`? `==` makes no sense here.

Comment: I was explaining assignment vs regular comparative. `===` takes it a step further. I did mention `===`, however what's the point if the op doesn't even know `==`?

Comment: I guess I assumed the items were objects, in which case `==` seems to not make sense to me.